# Preloading deeply nested associations in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

It's clear how to preload associations in Ecto 1-2 levels deep, such as post and comments to it.

I have an `Address`, and `Address` **belongs_to** a `Street`, and  `Street` **belongs_to** a `City`, and `City` **belongs_to** Region, and `Region` **belong_to** a `Country`

Given `Address`:

```
addr = Repo.get(Address, 123)
|> Repo.preload(street: ?????)
```

how do I preload it all the way to `Country`:

```
IO.puts("the name of country: #{addr.street.city.region.country.name}")
```

?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/3) `Repo.preload/3` is similar to `Ecto.Query.preload/3` and you can pass a nested list of preloads to both of them.

### Examples:

#### Using  `Repo.preload/3`:

```
addr = 
  Address
  |> Repo.get(123)
  |> Repo.preload(street: [city: [region: :country]])

IO.inspect(addr.street.city.region.country)
```

#### Using  `Ecto.Query.preload/3`:

```
addr = 
  Address
  |> Ecto.Query.where(id: 123)
  |> Ecto.Query.preload(street: [city: [region: :country]])
  |> Repo.one()

IO.inspect(addr.street.city.region.country)
```

Comment: What about preloads on the same level as street?  or city?  Like `preload(street: [city: [], base: [] ], boulevard: [])`

Comment: Yes, this should work. Also, if you don't have any sub-dependencies of city and base, you can simply write `preload(street: [:city,  :base], boulevard: [])`.